# How can i find the line number or file from which this error comes "_co.xyz variable is undefined" in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

I am trying to save the data which is entered from Angular 7 form, But when i submit there is issue occurs please see attached image. 
From where i can debug for Angular 7. And from where i can get the file name and line number? Because this error occurs in Angular js library. But it is not showing from where my code is wrong.
Can you help from where i can find a file where my code is wrong. 
Which file i need to check Component/Service etc..etc. 
Please help if anyone knows.

Comment: I have found the file and line, where this issue occurring.

Now, I can not get the input field value using 
"(click)="addBusiness(person_name.value, business_name.value, business_gst_number.value)""

Comment: I am using below code for Input field and on button click i am passing function like below,

<div *ngIf="angForm.controls['person_name'].invalid && (angForm.controls['person_name'].dirty || angForm.controls['person_name'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['person_name'].errors.required">
          Person Name is required.
        </div>
      </div>

<button (click)="addBusiness(person_name.value)"
        [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid" 
        class="btn btn-primary">
        Add Business
     </button>